# Is there any good software to convert (multilayer) DXF to shapefile?

Tags: command-line, cad, gis

I need to import architecture DWG's (AutoCAD files) into qGIS. 
However, QGIS imports all layers in the DXF into the same layer in QGIS. 
I need to create separate shapefiles for every DWG/DXF layer.

Is there any command line tool that can create a shapefile for every layer in a DWG ?

Comment: Is it not possible to split up the created shapefile in QGIS according to attribution in the shapefile?